# References on non-homogeneous boundary valued problems

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I know that J. L. Lions and E. Magenes's book "Non-Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications" is a classical reference on this topic. But it is too long and overkill. Actually,  I only want to learn about the second-order elliptic problems.  Does anyone know some short notes?

Comment: In which type of equation (elliptic, parabolic, hyperbolic,...) are you interested in?

Comment: I want to learn about the elliptic equations